# Why "FindTextPreferences" not working?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-server

I have 1 Font missing : `[ddddの]`. I want find and replace to Font `[Ab]`
This is  my Code, but it can't  find .

```
>  oIndesign.FindTextPreferences = 1851876449
>     oIndesign.ChangeTextPreferences = 1851876449
>     oIndesign.FindTextPreferences.AppliedFont = "ddddの"
>     oIndesign.FindTextPreferences.FontStyle = "Regular"
>     oIndesign.ChangeTextPreferences.AppliedFont = "Ab"
>     oIndesign.ChangeTextPreferences.FontStyle = "R"
>     Dim oaTargetList = oDocument.ChangeText
```

But If name of Font missing is: `[dddd]`. It working ok.
Why "FindTextPreferences" not working?, If font name contain Japanese.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that a "missing font" has not instantiated a Font Object that the F/C dialog can match. You may want to discard the font setting and inspect the font name for each result given that the font name is still accessible even if font is missing.

It would be worth looking if you couldn't reach those texts through the preflight panel by scripting.